# Flutter Problem with textformfield, the input does not center

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a problem with multiline chat input. When the user enter the chat, the input should be centered in the Container. However it is not the case and I can't fix it with padding.

Here is the screenschot of what I get : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6qeK.jpg)

What I should get instead :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JORQO.jpg)

Here is the code :

```
Container(
            width: screenWidth - 130.0,
            height: 30.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
            child: new ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 300.0),
              child: ScrollConfiguration(
                behavior: DisableScrollGlow(),
                child: new Scrollbar(
                  child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    reverse: true,
                    child: Center(
                      child: new TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        autofocus: true,
                        maxLines: null,
                        controller: _messageController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding:
                            EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, bottom: 0.0, top: 0.0, right: 0),
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

All help is welcomed

Comment: Do you want to center the text inside the textfield? If so you can use `textAlign: TextAlign.center` on the TextField.

Comment: This is not what I mean, I have added screenshot to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Sir_Joan_the_third,

I'm not shure, why you create the TextField in the widgets you choose, but as I tried to improve your code I had a problem when the input changes to multiple lines.
That's why I code the TextField without the widgets you used.
With this code, the Text was centered fine and no problems with multiple lines.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TempTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TempTestState createState() => _TempTestState();
}

class _TempTestState extends State<TempTest> {
  TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Center(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.image), onPressed: () => print('add photo')),
            trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.send), onPressed: () => print('send text')),
            title: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              autofocus: true,
              maxLines: null,
              controller: _messageController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, bottom: 0.0, top: 0.0, right: 0),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none),
                ),
                filled: true,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Result with ListTile:**
(without the dense property)

[image: Example with multiple line input]

## UPDATE

To minimize the padding of the Words inside the `TextField`, try the `isDense=true` property in the `TextField` and set the `contentPadding` to 0. Mainly like Alex Collette wrote in his answer.

It should look like this

[image]
[image]

with the following code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SmallInputField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SmallInputFieldState createState() => _SmallInputFieldState();
}

class _SmallInputFieldState extends State<SmallInputField> {
  TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Material(
              elevation: 5.0,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(1.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                child: Text('anger',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black87)),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              dense: true,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              leading: IconButton(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 24),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.image),
                  onPressed: () => print('add photo')),
              trailing: IconButton(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 24),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () => print('send text')),
              title: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                autofocus: true,
                maxLines: null,
                controller: _messageController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  isDense: true,
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 0, top: 0.0, right: 0),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, is there a way to make the TextField thinnier?

Comment: Hi @Sir_Joan_the_third, yes, when you use the code above the `isDense` property is true, the gif was with `isDense=false`. Check, if this fit's your needs.

Comment: The bottom and top padding are still too big. Even with isDense: true

Comment: @Sir_Joan_the_third you could use the `Row` Widget instead of the `ListTile` which has a height property we can't change so easily. Check if the new Code fits your needs.

Comment: Thank you very muchk, however, I was talking about padding in the InputField. Look at my second screenshot in my post, the TextField much more centered around the text, even if the text has the same size

Comment: @Sir_Joan_the_third I Updated the code  and added some pictures, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Set textAlign to TextAlign.center like this:

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  autofocus: true,
  maxLines: null,
  controller: controller,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding:
    EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, bottom: 0.0, top: 0.0, right: 0),
    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    border: InputBorder.none,
    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none),
),
```

Comment: This is not what I mean, I have added screenshots which describe the issue

Answer (score 0):

In Text Field Decoration keep dense equal to true

```
isDense : true
```

and in the content padding add

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, bottom: 5, top: 0.0, right: 0),
```